# Invalid shape () for image data using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I have the following two functions:

```
def Rs(n1,n2,o):
    numerador = n1*np.cos(o) - n2*np.sqrt(1-(n1*np.sin(o)/n2)**2)
    denominador = n1*np.cos(o) + n2*np.sqrt(1-(n1*np.sin(o)/n2)**2)
    return (np.abs(numerador/denominador))**2

def Rp(n1,n2,o):
    numerador = - n2*np.cos(o) + n1*np.sqrt(1-(n1*np.sin(o)/n2)**2)
    denominador = n2*np.cos(o) + n1*np.sqrt(1-(n1*np.sin(o)/n2)**2)
    return (np.abs(numerador/denominador))**2
```

And I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

o2 = np.linspace(0, np.pi/2, 90) # Array amb les thetes
n2 = np.linspace(1.5, 3.5, 90) # Array amb els index n2


O2, N2 = np.meshgrid(o2, n2) # Meshgrid per crear el pla on avaluar la funcio


  Imatge = Rs(n1, N2, O2)
  Imatge2 = Rp(n1, N2, O2)
 
  
#plt.imshow(Imatge, cmap = 'nipy_spectral')
#plt.colorbar()


  fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
  fig.suptitle("Rp i Rs en funcio de theta i n2")
  axs[0].imshow(Imatge, cmap = 'nipy_spectral')
  axs[0].set_title(r'$R_s ( \theta _i )$')
  axs[0].set_xlabel(r'$\theta $')
  axs[0].set_ylabel('$n_2$')
  axs[1].imshow(Imatge2, cmap = 'nipy_spectral')
  axs[1].set_title(r'$R_p ( \theta _i )$')
  axs[1].set_xlabel(r'$\theta $')
  axs[1].set_ylabel('$n_2$')
  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.show()
```

This code seems to be correctly and outputs the adjunted image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOxSD.png)

My question is why it works if I am passing the matrix O2 and N2 as parameter to functions Rs and Rp, when I should pass integer values?

Instead of that, the following code represents that it should work, because I am passing to functions integer values of the matrix iteration over echa row and column, but it doesnt work. I dont understand the cause of the problem:

```
import numpy as np

o2 = np.linspace(0, np.pi/2, 90) # Array amb les thetes
n2 = np.linspace(1.5, 3.5, 90) # Array amb els index n2


O2, N2 = np.meshgrid(o2, n2) # Meshgrid per crear el pla on avaluar la funcio

for i,j in enumerate(O2):
  for k,l in enumerate(j):
    print (i,k)
    Imatge = Rs(n1, N2[i][k], O2[i][k])
    Imatge2 = Rp(n1, N2[i][k], O2[i][k])
    
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
    fig.suptitle("Rp i Rs en funcio de theta i n2")
    axs[0].imshow(Imatge, cmap = 'nipy_spectral')
    axs[0].set_title(r'$R_s ( \theta _i )$')
    axs[0].set_xlabel(r'$\theta $')
    axs[0].set_ylabel('$n_2$')
    axs[1].imshow(Imatge2, cmap = 'nipy_spectral')
    axs[1].set_title(r'$R_p ( \theta _i )$')
    axs[1].set_xlabel(r'$\theta $')
    axs[1].set_ylabel('$n_2$')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

In this code the error is in the line "axs[0].imshow(Imatge, cmap = 'nipy_spectral')" and the error code is :Invalid shape () for image data

I tried to pass to function the values of the matrix instead of passing them all the matrix. The code that works is not seems to be logical for me.

Comment: fig.su**p**title ???

Comment: @wwii yes, it is correct.

Comment: You might want to read more about numpy's magic [array programming](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-speedup-data-processing-with-numpy-vectorization-12acac71cfca).